# Loop in directive and ng-change Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the next problem, I created a directive in Angular JS to check if input is or not a number, If it isn't number is neccesary set the right value. Here is my directive code:

```
app.directive('numberValidate', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attr, modelCtrl){

            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue){

                var transformedInput = parseInt(inputValue); 

                if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
                   modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                   modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return transformedInput;                
            });
        }
    };
});
```

additional I need to listen when the user stop typping to send a request. To listen when stop I've added `ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}"` to the field, as it is on the next code:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="sendChecker()" ng-model="identification" ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}" number-validate>
```

`sendChecker` function fires my request to the server, everything is working Ok when I write a number like `12345` or I type a number with characteres `12345a` this is converted to number and set in the input, The issue is when I write a letter `a` this creates a loop. How can I avoid this?

Any advice would be apreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking that transformedInput is actually a number?

Comment: Try the isNaN() function at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp

Comment: Maybe just use input type number? Shortcut, but it only accepts numbers. Then work the rest out.

Comment: @alphapilgrim If I detect is not number, I have set the right on the input text in this case `12345a` would be `12345`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use `ng-pattern` to validate your input?

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern=/^[0-9]+$/ ng-model="identification" ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}">
```

Or you can use input type `number`

```
 <input type="number" ng-model="identification" ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}">
```

Then you don't have to validate something by your own?

**Edit:**

In the following example `sendChecker()` is only called if user inserted a valid value

```
<form name="myform">
     <input type="number" name="myinput" ng-changed="myform.myinput.$valid ? sendChecker(identification) : " ng-model="identification" ng-model-options="{debounce: 750}">
</form>
```

Comment: How would you recommend set the value in case `ng-pattern`? I mean if isn't integer I must set the number value

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Which value you want to set? To match numbers only you can use the pattern from my example.

Comment: Why you want change the content of input field?

Comment: Becuase the value of input on the request must be a number, and the value after the directive go to `sendChecker` method to be sent

Answer (score 0):

Because `parseInt('12345a') == 12345` you get into loop. So you need to either filter out the non digits from string.

Comment: When I write `12345a` the behaviour is right, the problem is when I write `a` this is what create the loop.